# Let $X$ be the union of axes is it homeomorphic to a line, a circle, a parabola or the rectangular hyperbola $xy = 1$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $X$ be the union of axes given by $xy = 0$ in $\Bbb R^2$ . Is it homeomorphic to a line, a circle, a parabola or the rectangular hyperbola $xy = 1$?

If we remove the origin from the union of axes given by $xy = 0$ in $\Bbb R^2$, then we get $4$ connected pieces. Let if possible let there be an homeomorphism. But if we remove the image of the origin from the image sets, we get the following:

- One piece in case of the circle.
- Two pieces in case of a line.
- Two pieces in case of a parabola.
- Three pieces in case of rectangular hyperbola $xy = 1$.

Thus if true homeomorphism exists and since connectedness is a topological property then it would send four connected pieces of  the union of axes given by $xy = 0$ in $\Bbb R^2$ to four connected pieces each of a line, a circle, a parabola or the rectangular hyperbola $xy = 1$, which is not true. So no homeomorphism exists.

Is the proof correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct: $X$ is not homeomorphic to any of the choices, and your reasoning is correct. You can also rule out the rectangular hyperbola by noting that it is not connected, while $X$ is connected, and you can also rule out the circle by noting that it’s compact, while $X$ is not.