# Prove that $A$ with the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $A=${$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | xy=0$} with the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1232290/9464

Comment: I think that $\mathbb{R}-{0}$ is connected and $A-{f(0,0)}$ is not connected, where $f$ is an application from $\mathbb{R}$ to $A$ @Jack

Comment: How many parts are if you remove $(0,0)$? What about the corresponding point in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I restrict f in $\mathbb{R} -0$ @copper.hat

Comment: A homeomorphism will preserve connected components.

Comment: How would you do it? @copper.hat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is such a homeomorphism $f$.

Consider $A \setminus \{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{f(0)\}$.

The first has 4 connected components, the second has two.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for help!